# Background Color of Material UI Snackbar not being overridden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm doing an ErrorHandler in React.JS that pops up a Material UI Snackbar whenever there is an error caught by the ErrorHandler. The problem is that I want the `backgroundColor` style attribute red, but it does not change to a red color.

Could anyone guide me on how can I achieve the color change?

I have tried:

1. Using the `className` attribute on the Snackbar component.
2. Using the `ContentProps` prop.
3. Using CSS overriding styles with classes.

The ErrorHandler.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ErrorIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Error';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import SnackbarContent from '@material-ui/core/SnackbarContent';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import styles from "./errorHandlerStyles";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hasError: false,
            error: ""
        };

        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidCatch(error) {
        this.setState({ 
            hasError: true, 
            error: error 
        });
    }

    handleClose() { this.setState({ hasError: false }); }

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        if (this.state.hasError) {
            return (
                <Snackbar
                    classes={{
                        root: classes.root
                    }}
                    anchorOrigin={{
                        vertical: "bottom",
                        horizontal: "left"
                    }} 
                    autoHideDuration={5000}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    open={this.state.hasError}
                >
                    <SnackbarContent 
                        message={
                            <span className={classes.message}>
                                <ErrorIcon className={classes.icon} />
                                {this.state.error.toString()}
                            </span>
                        }
                        action={
                        <IconButton key="close" onClick={this.handleClose} className={classes.content}>
                            <CloseIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    }
                    >
                    </SnackbarContent>
                </Snackbar>
            );
        }
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

ErrorBoundary.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ErrorBoundary);
```

The errorHandlerStyles.js:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    message: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        fontSize: 16
    },
    icon: {
        fontSize: 20,
        opacity: 0.9,
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 1,
    },
    content: {
        margin: theme.spacing.unit * 1,
    },
    root: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.error.light
    }
});

export default styles;
```

Comment: Try to import styles  by import {styles} from "./errorHandlerStyles"

Comment: @HemaNandagopal Just tried it. It is still not changing the color.

Comment: Can you add it in fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<SnackbarContent>` component needs to receive the `background-color` styling, not the `<SnackBar/>`:

```
<SnackbarContent className={classes.root} />
```

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work. I have written it in the description of the issue :)

Comment: @minus.273 Updated answer! You need to style the SnackbarContent instead of the SnackBar, see example here: https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/#customized-snackbars

Answer (score 0):

Try using `className={classes.root}` on the `SnackbarContent` component.